# Почему не срабатывает min-width?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

[Сайт](http://www.gruzopereezd71.ru) - для нормального отображения на планшетах через media установил min-width: 1200px (по максимальной ширине контента). В итоге сайт будто приближен при расширении 1024x768.
Пробовал убирать  initial-scale=1 но результата нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 421px) {
    body {
        min-width: 1220px;
    }
}
```

тут условия противоречат сами себе

Comment: Мало. Ещё есть условие.  min-width - парный атрибут. Он не работает без max-width. Проверено на многих браузерах.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю в чем противоречие? Минимальная ширина экрана 421px, максимальная 1024px, получаем "вилку" между 421 и 1024

Comment: и ставим там минимальную ширину в 1200 пх, когда максимальная ширина стоит 1024